# Error when creating a database in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I save data in database, i get a DataException error. (See screenshot).

I am using a Repository and Service Layer in my project.

[image]

[image: http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-07/77443632388145685611.png]

And I use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in my DataBaseContext

```
public class DataBaseContext:DbContext
{
    static DataBaseContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataBaseContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Post> DbPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: visual studio is not getting your database .mdf file path..

Comment: how do i can do for fix this error?

Comment: I Use EntityFramework Coe First for model.


Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since your error description is not clear or not more detailed.

So, Below are my Assumptions:

- Double Check your `DB Column Name` and `Model Property Names` are the
  same spelled.
- Make sure you have passed the correct `Data Type Data` to
  Insert/Update.
- Since its displaying the Data Un handled exception so focus your data
  are proper.

**Have you checked the Inner Exception?**

If not go to `View Details` at the same error popup which is thrown. See the `inner exceptions for more details`. Post that exception description Here.